# Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php

I would think the following piece of code should work, but it doesn't **(Edited: Now works in PHP 5.5+)**:

```
if (!empty($r->getError()))
```

Where `getError()` is simply:

```
public function getError()
{
    return $this->error;
}
```

Yet I end up with this error:

> can't use method return value in write context

What does this mean? Isn't this just a read?

Comment: Probably in PHP 5.5 you will be permitted to pass expressions to `empty`: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/empty_isset_exprs

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: Ok i find [porneL's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4328049/476) 
 correct too this my code  `if ( !$e->find('div') ) ` that check if current HTML DOM element are empty or not . I use it inside loop to print out only single Div without inner Div inside it .

Answer (score 783, accepted):

`empty()` needs to access the value by reference (in order to check whether that reference points to something that exists), and PHP before 5.5 didn't support references to temporary values returned from functions.

However, the real problem you have is that you use `empty()` at all, mistakenly believing that "empty" value is any different from "false".

Empty is just an alias for `!isset($thing) || !$thing`. When the thing you're checking always exists (in PHP results of function calls always exist), the `empty()` function is *nothing but a negation operator*.

PHP **doesn't have concept of emptyness**. Values that evaluate to false are empty, values that evaluate to true are non-empty. It's the same thing. This code:

```
$x = something();
if (empty($x)) …
```

and this:

```
$x = something();
if (!$x) …
```

has **always the same result, in all cases, for all datatypes** (because `$x` is defined `empty()` is redundant).

Return value from the method always exists (even if you don't have `return` statement, return value exists and contains `null`). Therefore:

```
if (!empty($r->getError()))
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
if ($r->getError())
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the one currently selected.

Comment: empty() equals !$x for most purposes, not for all var types.

Comment: @gcb: no, the PHP manual explicitly says it's identical: *"empty() is the opposite of `(boolean) var`, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set."*

Comment: The not generating a warning part is pretty important... empty($var) will return true if it's 0, '', array(), NULL, or not even defined.  It's good practice, particularly so you can log your *real* warnings without the files filling up

Comment: Ok, great answer, but what's the right way to avoid this, does anyone know?

Comment: @Javatar: The last line of porneLs answer shows how to avoid the PHP-exception in question - in most cases.  To solve it in all cases you have to check $r for its existence & type explicitly to gain the same robustness of using empty(): "if (isset($r) AND is_object($r) AND $r->getError()) { ..then.. }"

Comment: Instead checking for !empty($r->getError()) can we use "null!==$r->getError()" ? What do you think?

Comment: @EugenMihailescu in general that's ok, but it's not strictly equivalent to empty(), because `""`, `0`, etc. are "empty", but not null.

Comment: Not really true. `if (empty($x['non_existing_index']))` and `if (!$x['non_existing_index'])` produce different results.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that earns PHP its reputation, and no amount of charmed circle legalism around a subject, as in this upvoted answer, will fix this. We may wish we could always use php7, but realities intrude. I think there are two sensible solutions if at least 5.3 is present. Use an intermediate value per George Claghom, Luke P M. Or, there is the Elvis operator, so $val = function()) ?: false; should be good, to give something we can trust to further php logic. If trust is the word....

Comment: No need to keep fighting about true being something and false not being nothing, your answer was very clear but as a precision, is it because of the referencing that if you return an array from your function you can do `if( empty(foo()[ 'bar' ]) ){
  echo 'foo bar';
}` but if you call only the function it crash `if( empty(foo()) ){
  echo 'foo dies';
}`

Comment: So if there is no empty why mislead developers by calling the function empty?

Comment: This answer is wrong in that `empty($a)` is not an alias for `!isset($a)` E.g. `$a = false;` then `!isset($a)` will be false, while `empty($a)` will be true. They are quite different. IMHO `empty()` is *the* most useful function in PHP. So much so that I port it to JavaScript.

Comment: @geoidesic You've misread the answer, which states `!isset($thing) || !$thing`. Note the second part after `||` that you're missing in your comment.

Answer (score 331):

> **Note:** This is a very high voted answer with a high visibility, but please note that it promotes bad, unnecessary coding practices! See [@Kornel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328049/476) for the correct way.
>
> **Note #2:** I endorse the suggestions to use [@Kornel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328049/476). When I wrote this answer three years ago, I merely meant to explain the nature of the error, not necessarily endorse the alternative.  The code snippet below is not recommended.

---

It's a limitation of [empty()](https://www.php.net/empty) in PHP versions below 5.5.

> Note: empty() only checks variables as
> anything else will result in a parse
> error. In other words, the following
> will not work: empty(trim($name)).

You'd have to change to this

```
// Not recommended, just illustrates the issue
$err = $r->getError();
if (!empty($err))
```

Comment: This is insanely counterproductive.

Comment: Note: The same is true with `isset()`.

ie: `isset($this->foo->getBar())` will result in the same issue.

Comment: porneL's answer explains this in more detail, with a better solution

Comment: @SystemParadox - Depends on what you mean by "better".  porneL's answer is arguably more thorough with a "cleaner" solution, but also doesn't actually explain the origin of the error either.

Comment: `if ($r->getError() != '')` would also work, though not as thorough

Comment: Agreed, porneL's answer is a lot better than this answer.

Comment: Because it's not wrong, @deceze. It's not the best answer, you won't get any argument from me there. I even voted up porneL's myself. It's a *very old* answer but it's not *wrong*. Regarding the high votes: remember, porneL's arrived nearly a full 17 months after this one.

Comment: I was going insane when I was trying to fix a bug in my application until I saw this post and then I realized my php version was 5.3. After I upgraded my version to 5.5, It worked like a charm. This is a life saving answer even after its been so long. Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

Prior to PHP 5.5, the [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) used to say:

> empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error

In PHP < 5.5 you weren't able use `empty()` directly on a function's return value.  Instead, you could assign the return from `getError()` to a variable and run `empty()` on the variable.

In PHP >= 5.5 this is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 19):

I usually create a global function called is_empty() just to get around this issue

```
function is_empty($var)
{ 
 return empty($var);
}
```

Then anywhere I would normally have used empty() I just use is_empty()

Comment: It's better not to do this and stick to the standards (as annoying as they might be).

Comment: @dynamism could you explain why not?

Comment: Because convenience functions can be a pain to read in someone else's code. Plus, in a MVC/HMVC architecture it can mess your structure. At the end of the day, PHP coders should know it's limitations and be able to understand small workarounds without convenience functions.

Comment: Wow, you've just invented a *negation function*. You know PHP has `!` operator for this? :)

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by others, it's a (weird) limitation of empty().

For most purproses, doing this is equal as calling empty, but this works:

```
if ($r->getError() != '')
```

Comment: This isn't true - `empty()` covers many more possibilities than just a blank string

Comment: That's why it says "for *most purposes*", not *all*

Answer (score 2):

The issue is this, you want to know if the error is not empty.

```
public function getError() {
    return $this->error;
}
```

Adding a method isErrorSet() will solve the problem.

```
public function isErrorSet() {
    if (isset($this->error) && !empty($this->error)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now this will work fine with this code with no notice.

```
if (!($x->isErrorSet())) {
    echo $x->getError();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would be a common mistake, but if you do something like:

```php
$var = 'value' .= 'value2';
```

this will also produce the same error

> Can't use method return value in write context

You can't have an `=` and a `.=` in the same statement. You can use one or the other, but not both.

Note, I understand this is unrelated to the actual code in the question, however this question is the top result when searching for the error message, so I wanted to post it here for completeness.

Answer (score -3):

The alternative way to check if an array is empty could be:

```
count($array)>0
```

It works for me without that error