# Zend Framework: Check if Zend View Placeholder isset

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

How can I check if a Zend View Placeholder isset before echo-ing it out? As I am wanting to prepend " - " to it before outputting it.

I tried

```
echo isset($this->placeholder('title')) 
    ? ' - ' . $this->placeholder('title') 
    : '';
```

But I got

> Fatal error: Can't use method return
>   value in write context in
>   D:\Projects\Websites\php\ZendFramework\LearningZF\application\layouts\scripts\layout.phtml
>   on line 5

On a side note, how come when I got this error, why isn't it shown in the Error View Script? The error was shown in a blank page without layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the cause of the fatal error see the Question [PHP : can’t use method return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/php-cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context).

So you could either use a temporary variable or `$this->placeholder()->getRegistry()->containerExists("key")` which returns a boolean.

```
echo ($this->placeholder()->getRegistry()->containerExists("title")) ? " - " . $this->placeholder("title") : "";
```

Comment: This was a great idea in theory, but I got a Fatal Error with your solution.. :( plus I discovered a much simpler one.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this:

```
// get a placeholder registry instance and create a container
$registry = Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry::getRegistry();
$myPlaceholder = $registry->createContainer('myPlaceholder');
```

Then you may check if a placeholder exists with:

```
$registry->containerExists('myPlaceholder')
```

Or check the contents of your placeholder with:

```
$myPlaceholder->getValue();
```

And of course, render by simply echoing it.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder::placeholder() in /library/Zend/View/Helper/Placeholder.php on line 72
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: name in /library/Zend/View/Helper/Placeholder.php on line 74
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container::getRegistry() in /path/to/index.phtml on line 109

Per my comment to Benjamin Cremer's answer (fatal error shown above), I came up with a nice simple solution:

```
$content = $this->placeholder('placeholderName')->getValue();
if (!empty($content)) {
    echo $content;
}
```