# Zend Framework 2 : Check if placeholder is set (or not empty)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Like the question for [Zend Framework 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300724/zend-framework-check-if-zend-view-placeholder-isset), what is the proper way to test if a placeholder value is set (or if it contains content)?

I know I could do

```
$content = $this->placeholder('something')->getValue();
if (!empty($content)) {
   echo $content;
}
```

but I'd rather check this directly. Something like

```
if (.. test $this->placeholder('something') has content ..) {
   echo $this->placeholder('something');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this three liner:

```
if (null != ($content = $this->placeholder('something')->getValue())) {
    echo $content;
}
```

It's not exactly equal to empty, but it's coming close. It'll display "0" where as empty() would not. See [this](http://codepad.org/Q1VLT6hQ) codepad