# Zend View Action Helper $params questions

Tags: zend-framework

i am wondering by what method are the params of a zend view action helper passed by? `get` or `post`. is is becos i cant seem to access them via `$_GET` & `$_POST` but i can with `$this->getRequest()->getParam("xxx")`

then i want to check if the variable exists 1st before using it so i did

```
$itemsPerPage = isset($this->getRequest()->getParam("itemsPerPage")) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam("itemsPerPage") : 5;
```

which fails with

> Fatal error: Can't use method return
>   value in write context in
>   D:\Projects\Websites\php\ZendFramework\LearningZF\application\controllers\IndexController.php
>   on line 21

i wonder whats wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a default value to be returned if the parameter is not set

```
$itemsPerPage = $this->getRequest()->getParam('itemsPerPage', 5)
```

For the cause of your error have a look over [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/php-cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context), the same applies for `isset()`.

```
function getFoo()
{
    return 'foo';
}

var_dump(isset(getFoo()); // causes Fatal error

$foo = getFoo();
var_dump(isset($foo)); // prints "boolean true"
```

Comment: oh so `isset` will only check variables not return value from functions?

Comment: Exactly: "isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error."