# How to "rtrim" a PHP array (remove empty elements ONLY towards the END of the array) and avoid a for or similar loop if possible

Tags: php, arrays

Much like `rtrim()` to a string, how do I remove the empty elements of an array only after the last non-empty element towards the end of the array while avoiding a `for` or similar loop and possibly using PHP's array functions instead?

I'm actually looking for the fastest/most efficient/elegant way, but if this is not possible without a `for` or similar loop or I'm mistaken about "fast/efficient/elegant" especially with PHP's array functions then I'd be more than happy to learn/know what's best. Thanks.

Other assumptions:

1. There can be a series of single or consecutive empty elements before the last non-empty element in the array.
2. No need to worry about an empty array, but if this case is covered it's totally fine.

For example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ""
    [1] => "text"
    [2] => "text"
    [3] => ""
    [4] => "text"
    [5] => ""
    [6] => ""
    [7] => "text"
    [8] => ""
    [9] => ""
)
```

would end up being:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ""
    [1] => "text"
    [2] => "text"
    [3] => ""
    [4] => "text"
    [5] => ""
    [6] => ""
    [7] => "text"
)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [0] => "text"
    [1] => "text"
    [2] => "text"
    [3] => "text"
    [4] => "text"
    [5] => "text"
    [6] => "text"
    [7] => ""
    [8] => ""
    [9] => ""
)
```

would end up being:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "text"
    [1] => "text"
    [2] => "text"
    [3] => "text"
    [4] => "text"
    [5] => "text"
    [6] => "text"
)
```

Comment: short of doing a `for`, i tried array_filter(), but i realized that also removes the other empty elements before the end of the array.

Comment: oh, sorry @webarto, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's like you wrote it in your question: As long as the last value is an empty string, remove it from the array:

```
while ("" === end($array))
{
    array_pop($array);
}
```

**Edit:** I have no clue how serious this is, however for the fun, I've come up with this which does not uses any loop in user-code, however, loops are involved for sure inside PHP C functions. Probably this can make a difference, no idea, to enjoy responsively:

```
$array = array_slice($array, 0, key(array_reverse(array_diff($array, array("")), 1))+1);
```

How it works:

- Get an array with all values that are not in `array("")`. Keys will be preserved (that's the important part, the keys in your array are 0-n).
- Get the key of the last element.
- Slice the array from start to that position.

Comment: sweet jellybeans yes! how could've i missed that? hakre yerra legend. thanks! (sorry have to wait 4 more minutes to accept the answer..) and @webarto, at least it doesn't always have to loop through the whole array.

Comment: @AnaBan, in any case it doesn't :) +1

Comment: @webarto i see.. what if the whole array is filled with empty values? its count would still be > 0.. hm.. or am i getting this wrong again? thanks, am learnin a lot..

Comment: @Ana Ban: If the whole array is empty, than looking from the back means it would take the longest possible time. PHP.net has a long,  [long list of array functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), read through it, it's worth anyway, maybe there is some gem in there that will do it. I'll look as well.

Comment: totally, been lookin through it lots, thanks much! anyways, the whole-array-empty case is an extreme one, so i'll leave it at that for now. thanks again

Comment: @AnaBan: With "only" three build in array functions, I was able to do it. See the updated answer.

Comment: oh my word that's sexy! the beauty of the edit is it saved me 1 more step, coz that `key`'s exactly what am lookin fer! absolutely spot on!

Comment: Seems this does not work for empty entries., If I do `while (empty(end($array)))` I get ***Can't use function return value in write context***

Comment: @mplungjan: You most likely meant `while(!end($array))` however, if you want to understand that error in more detail, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1075534/367456 and if you want to understand why you're using `empty` wrong see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4328049/367456

Comment: No I meant what I said. Your code only works if there is an actual space in the array. Thanks for the explanation. I ended up reversing like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8663367/295783

Comment: What's great about the `while` solution, is that's it's clean and instantly understandable. I can't understand the array function chain after only 5 seconds, so TL;DR.

Comment: one day i got forever while loop. To avoid this, i made adjustment to your solution:                 while (count($array)>0 && "" == end($array))
                {
                    array_pop($array);
                }

Comment: @TomasŠivickas: Always use `===` for the comparison (strict equal) otherwise you're asking for trouble in PHP (well most often, here in the while for sure).

Answer (score 4):

Use `trim()` or `rtrim()` as you need it:

```
explode( '·', trim( implode( '·', $test ), '·') );
```

It changes …

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => text
    [2] => text
    [3] => 
    [4] => text
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => text
    [8] => 
)
```

… to …

```
Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => text
    [2] => 
    [3] => text
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => text
)
```

Comment: What if your delimiter you set in "implode" is used within one of the values within the original array?

Comment: Then it will break. If you cannot control the content, you’ll need @hakre’s solution.

Comment: Right - I was just pointing out that you really can't use array to string manipulation when you need to go back and forth from array like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_rtrim($array)
{
    $array = array_reverse($array);
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    if ((string) $value === '') unset($array[$key]); else break 1;
    return array_reverse($array);
}
```

...

```
$array = array('', 1, 2, 3, '', 0, '', '');
print_r(array_rtrim($array));
```

...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 
    [5] => 0
)
```

Comment: So long as a member isn't `'0'`.

Comment: `if (!empty($value)) break; unset($array[$key]);` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!end($array)) { array_pop($array); };
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you rebuild your array, use `array_values` to rebuild the indexes.

```
array_walk_recursive('unset_any_null_values_function', $array);

print_r(array_values($array));
```