# PHP empty() strange behaviour

Tags: php

The following code (#1):

```
var_dump($myObject->getBook()->getCollection());
$testArray=Array();
var_dump($testArray);
var_dump(empty($testArray));
```

...will output:

```
array(0) { } array(0) { } bool(true)
```

The following code (#2):

```
var_dump($myObject->getBook()->getCollection());
$testArray=Array();
var_dump($testArray);
var_dump(empty($myObject->getBook()->getCollection()));
```

...will output:

Nothing. No error, not a single character. No nothing.

```
class Book{
  protected $bidArray=Array();
  public function getCollection(){
    return $this->bidArray;
  }
}
```

What is happening there?

Comment: Is displaying errors turned on?

Comment: Yes, they are turned on!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is **not** a function, although it looks like a one. It's just a special syntax that works *only* with variables, e.g. `empty($abc)`. You simply cannot use expressions such as `empty(123)` or `empty($obj->getSth())`.

Comment: Yeah. Just stored the return value of `getCollection()` in a variable before using `empty()`. PHP is sick.

Comment: @Dyin *PHP is sick.* - I couldn't agree more. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `empty()` with anything other than variable (that means no function call as well).

`var_dump(empty($myObject->getBook()->getCollection()));`

You must have your error display turned off, as the following:

```
<?php

class Bar {
        function foo() {
        }
}

$B = new Bar();
empty($B->foo());
```

Gives

> PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context in D:\cw\home\andreas\test\empty.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in D:\cw\home\andreas\test\empty.php on line 9

On my local.

Try doing `ini_set('display_errors', true)` prior to your `var_dump`'s and see if the error messages crop up

Comment: Tired to set `display_errors` as you mentioned. Still no output. Got fatal errors from elsewhere BTW. Using PHP 5.3.8 with XAMPP.

Comment: @Dyin hmm, also try with `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL)` along with `display_errors`, see if that helps

Answer (score 2):

As on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse
>   error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)).

This is because `empty()` isn't a function, but a language construct and therefore limited to this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Using empty() you can't check directly against the return value of a method. More info here: [Can't use method return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)