# php cannot check if a PDO result is empty using empty() returns FATAL ERROR

Tags: php, pdo, fatal-error

I want to check whether my prepared query has returned empty or not without having to go into a loop. This is the code I have tried using:

```
if(empty($pQuery1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){}
```

When I try this I get the error:

`Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context`

Whether I  use `PDO->fetchALL` or `PDO->fetch` I receive the same error. Should I be doing something differently?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to assign the results to a variable, then call `empty()` on the variable. It's just an annoying limitation of the `empty()` function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context) question.

```
$results = $pQuery1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (empty($results)){}
```

Comment: id like to point out you might as well just do `if (!$results) {}` as it behaves identically.

Comment: @chris if(empty($foo)) won't generate a warning if the parameter isn't set.   if(!$foo) will generate a warning if the parameter isn't set. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: it was set on the previous line :)

Comment: @chris - using `$results` in such a way only fails if the result returns false. It is possible to have an empty result without being false.

Comment: That is a pretty annoying limitation. I wounder when if it will be corrected.

Comment: @BrookJulias, the ! operator converts its operand to boolean, and empty array converts to boolean false. ! operator and empty() are 100% logically equivalent.

Comment: @Chris - I must have messed up some of my testing.