# Meaning of "Can't use method return value in write context"

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't use method return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

I sometimes encountered this error `Can't use method return value in write context`. However, I don't know what does `WRITE CONTEXT` means in this sentence. Could someone tell me a little general explaination of it.

Thank you.

The code for this error if you want to refer to is on line `if(empty($this->loadUser()))` However just to clarify, I just want to find out the meaning of "write context":

```
public function verify()
{
    if(empty($this->loadUser()))
        $this->addError('username','Incorrect username.');
    else
    {
        $user = $this->loadUser();
        $project = $this->loadProject($pid);

        $project->associateUserToProject($this->loadUser());
        $project->associateUserToRole($this->role, $this->user->id)

    }
}

public function loadUser() {
    return User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
}
```

Comment: You will find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context?rq=1 and the possible duplicate of that.

Answer (score 1):

empty () is not a function really.
It is a construct or macros, if you please.
It means you cannot pass an object to it as argument.
Just pure variables.

```
$is_use = $this->loadUser();
if (empty ($is_use))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`empty` only takes variables as an arg. `empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error.`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php