# PHP fatal error Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php

I have seen this question being asked many times, but I am yet confused and came across something similar condition. I am not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context) and my context are same or not, as long as I am convinced this is a different scenario or else I might have misunderstood the explanation. 
O.k. here is my scenario:

```
$amount = isset($cost->getCostAmount()) ? $cost->getCostAmount() : 0;
```

Function costAmount() is dynamically added during run-time and it may or may not exist. So I need to first check if my function exists or not and rest is pretty clear. But now in this case I get a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in ..../file.php

Now if I do something like this:

```
$amount = $cost->getCostAmount() ? $cost->getCostAmount() : 0;
```

Obviously I would get an error:

> Call to undefined method: getCostAmount

if the function doesn't exist. What could be a possible solution for this? Explanation will be considered helpful.

> Request: Please add an adequate comment to why the question has been downvoted so that I would be able to improve my questions, in the future.

Comment: It means there is no method `getCostAmount()`, what is `$cost` ?

Comment: [`function_exists`](http://php.net/function-exists)?

Comment: @MihaiIorga $cost is a object or some other class.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes I have already tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: @roko $cost has to be an initialized class for that to work.

Comment: Additionally, I've got this same error using `!empty($class->function())` on a function that returns an array, and definitely existed and as accessible.  Assigning the array to a variable prior to the `empty` check did the trick for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change this:

```
$amount = isset($cost->getCostAmount()) ? $cost->getCostAmount() : 0;
```

to..

```
$amount = method_exists($cost, 'getCostAmount') ? $cost->getCostAmount() : 0;
```

because this piece of code `isset($cost->getCostAmount())` is executing method `getCostAmount` even if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

`isset` requires you pass a variable to it not a function. It can not check *whether the return value is set*.

You should use it like this,

```
$cost_amount = $cost->getCostAmount();
$amount = isset($cost_amount) ? $cost_amount : 0;
```

Even this code does not make sense. Because here $cost_amount will be always set. If `getCostAmount` returns `null` or `empty` string you should check it that way.

```
$cost_amount = $cost->getCostAmount();
$amount = !is_null($cost_amount) ? $cost_amount : 0;
```

Also your code does not find `getCostAmount` function. If you know this is declared somewhere include it. If this method is generated dynamically you can check by using `method_exists`.

```
 $amount = method_exists($cost, 'getCostAmount')? $cost->getCostAmount(): 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the "isset requires you pass a variable to it not a function" but seems like you didn't get my context here, this would also return that the function doesn't exist.

Comment: yes now it would work ofcourse and I am very thankful as well but I donot know if you were in too much hurry but this came after I don't even know how many edits :) And no it wasn't that I hadn't tried it properly because when I last read it you only had two lines of code and that didn't make too much sense, infact those things were already mentioned in the question. Yet +1 for the explanations :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing isset() to function_exists()

Comment: If that's the only change, the method invocation will still be present and the error message will stay exactly the same; besides, `function_exists()` will not work as you expect when used on a _method_ and not a plain function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `method_exists` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) in the following way:

```
var_dump(method_exists($cost,'getCostAmount'));
```