# Can't use the method return value in write context

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, user-data

I'm using codeigniter and trying to make an if statement for if the controllers have changed. What I have right now gives the error.

```
if (isset($this->session->userdata('lastUrl')) && $this->session->userdata('lastUrl') != $this->router->class) {
     echo 'new controller';
}

$this->session->set_userdata('lastUrl', $this->router->class);
```

This code is in the constructor of the controller so it will be run on every page.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context but out of close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset` is a special language construct that can only be used on variables or array keys, not methods.  This should have the same functionality:

```
$this->session->userdata('lastUrl') !== null && ...
```

Answer (score 3):

you can check this by `method_exists()` function

```
if (method_exists($this->session->userdata('lastUrl')) && $this->session->userdata('lastUrl') != $this->router->class) {
     echo 'new controller';
}
```