# $this->_getParam in Zend Framework and empty()

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I'm submiting a form and I'm trying to check if a field is empty or not and I do this:

```
if(empty($this->_getParam('my_field')))
```

And It doesn't work, But this works if I just use `$_POST['my_field]`

`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Can't use method return value in write context in....`

How should I do this with `$this->_getParam` in order to work? since I guess is not such a good option to use `$_POST` on a framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem: ***Can't use method return value in write context***

Here's a good explanation why have to do this: [Can't use method return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context/4328049#4328049)

To use empty() you would have to first get the return value

```
$field = $this->_getParam('my_field');
if(empty($field)){
  //is empty
}
```

(Update: This is not an issue for PHP versions >= 5.5)  empty($this->_getParam('my_field')) would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

[`empty`](http://php.net/empty) - like `isset` - is not a real function, instead it's a language construct. So you can only use variables as its only *argument* (no expressions, no function results).

But, you can use a temporary variable:

```
$my_field = $this->_getParam('my_field');
if(empty($my_field))
....
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct.  An alernative would be to provide a default to your call to `_getParam()`, such as `null`.  Then you could call

```
is_null($this->_getParam('myfield',null))
```

This method might be preferable, because Zend already determines that parameter's emptiness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary variable

```
$field = $this->_getParam('my_field');

if(empty($field)){
  //you code here
}
```