# How to check an index is exist and not null in php

Tags: php, null, isset

I am always using the following code to check if an index exists and is not null:

```
if(!(isset($_POST['service']) and $_POST['service']))
   die('The service parameter is not available.');
```

Here I am checking two conditions. Is it possible to do it using a single buit-in function? eg:-

```
if(!isSetAndNotNull($_POST['service']))
   die('The service parameter is not available.');
```

Comment: `$_POST` values cannot be `null`, and `isset` is already checking for `null`. You're checking if the string is `false`.

Comment: If you'd have just checked the "see also" section of the php isset manual page (http://php.net/isset) you'd have seen a reference to the ```empty()``` function...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use empty() for that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

returns false for empty(false) or empty(null)

Comment: Great! I know the empty()! But I thought it is only useful for checking the null.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `empty` I would use `!`:

```
if(!$_POST['service'])
   die('The service parameter is not available.');
```

In case of using it with functions it avoid troubles.

Explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328049/1081396

Comment: You can read the problem you can find in the question of the link I posted. "Can't use method return value in write context"

Comment: The above code gives "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: service in ..."

Comment: @Steve That only exists if you use `empty` on a *function*, which it was not designed for and is not needed for. In this case he uses it for a variable, which is correct. The answer you link to explains why `empty` + function is wrong, not that you should always avoid `empty`.

Comment: Yeah, that's true @deceze. That's why i said *in some cases*. But you are right.

Comment: I can see your issue with empty(), but in his post-variable case it is just working fine. And youd better edit your if condition to `if(!$_POST['service'])`

Comment: Anyway, +1 for giving light to the issue with empty().