# Adding a if(); in Simple HTML dom parser function

Tags: php, if-statement, simple-html-dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t use method return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

What is the way to add a if statement in Simple HTML dom parser( http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ) function
Have a look at my script

```
include ('dom.php');
$check = file_get_html("http://www.google.com");
if(empty($check->find('div[id=domain]',0))){$same="NoData";} // line 3
else { $same = $check->find('div[id=domain]',0); }
```

Have a look at line 3! Here i want to add a if statement to check is there any div with the 'domain' attribute id at my targeted page! so, if it is empty that means that it has no div with the 'domain' attribute id so it should store `NoData` in `$same` variable. and if there is a div with the 'domain' attribute id then it will fetch the and store the name in `$same` variable. But `// line 3` showing an ugly error!
Error: `Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in C:\UwAmp\phpapps\uwamp\php\code.php on line 5`
 Any idea?

Comment: eeeee not a duplicate on

Comment: Its duplicate! And we need to close it fast. You need to change the line 3 `empty()` call See @deceze's url

Comment: @JessicaLingmn why you want to add this `if(empty($check->find('div[id=domain]',0))){$same="NoData";}` code?

Comment: so it will not show any error message if there is no data at my targeted page while fetching!

Comment: @Jessica This is *so* a duplicate. Have you actually read the answers there?

Answer (score 0):

Probably hiding the error message is a solution if you want to hide the first error message(error message if there is no data at the targeted page while fetching)
 so the `if();` statement is not necessary!
Add this code to the first line of code before any function in your php script

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: *Hiding errors* is never a solution.

Comment: @deceze have a look at her last comment, i think she want to hide the error message if there is no div with the 'domain' attribute id at her targeted page..

Comment: ***Hiding errors is never a solution.*** She has to check for the case where there is no domain attribute and handle it correctly, not let it generate an error which she ignores.