# Checking for CodeIgniter session_id to not be set

Tags: codeigniter, session, variables, set

I'm trying to check if its set in my codeigniter application like:

```
elseif(!isset($this->session->userdata('session_id'))){ ## SESSION data is NOT set
            // load a generic 'issue' occurred view.
        }
```

but I keep getting this error, is `!isset` not valid in Codeigniter? How do I go about easily checking this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the code like below:

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
// your other code
elseif(!isset($id)){ 
        // load a generic 'issue' occurred view.
}
```

The reason you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

Answer (score 0):

You coud also do this ,

```
elseif($this->session->userdata('session_id') !== false)
{
      // SESSION data is NOT set
      // load a generic 'issue' occurred view.
}
```

***Note: The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are trying to access does not exist.***