# using count in if statement and comparing with its returned value doesn't work

Tags: php

```
if(count($arr1) === count($arr2) === 26)
```

In the above line it is throwing error

```
syntax error, unexpected '==='
```

Why can't i compare the value returned by count() with 26

Comment: That's just invalid PHP syntax. You'll have to split up the comparisons and use `&&`

Comment: -1 because really low quality

Comment: Well, I think this should have worked. At first, `count($arr2) === 26` should be evaluated to boolean `true` or `false`. Then `count($arr1)` should be (strictly) compared to boolean, giving `false` in any case. So why does this produce error? (I don't mean this makes something different than OP wants, but it should be valid -- I vote up).

Comment: @hek2mgl it's not low quality, many guys stucked with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context?rq=1

Comment: It's **really** low quality and a duplicate as you have shown. Sorry, please don't take it personal. Just try to fix your errors for yourself. If it not works try harder, investigate! but don't ask such questions on SO

Comment: @Voitcus see the accepted answer

Comment: @MarkEvans Yes I have, but no syntax error would be if second comparison is in brackets: `if($a == ($b == $c))` has no syntax error (doesn't matter if use `==` or `===`), but in `if($a == $b == $c)` there is one. So the accepted answer is not 100% correct.

Comment: @MarkEvans I don't wanted to be offensive or something like that. I just wanted to say, if you want to get a programmer you'll have to learn to fix such problems for yourself. (Again, not offensive): Use the [manual](http://php.net/docs.php) it is **really** helpful.

Comment: @hek2mgl I think I really didn't made any efforts to investigate the problem and made some silly mistakes.

Comment: @MarkEvans Ok. :) However it is not so important anyway. it's just a question on SO (one out of 5 million :) .. You'll learn to fix such problems for yourself, I'm sure.. cu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `count($arr2)` is 26

```
if(count($arr1) === count($arr2) === 26)
```

evaluates to

```
if(count($arr1) === True)
```

which would then fail.

You need to perform two logic checks and check they both evaluate to true

Comment: does it checks it backwards

Comment: Yes, from right to left

Comment: I've written the same in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168889/using-count-in-if-statement-and-comparing-with-its-returned-value-doesnt-work#comment24857263_17168889), but there is a syntax error here.

Answer (score 4):

You can but you have to do it separately:

```
if(count($arr1) === 26 && count($arr2) === 26)
```