# using a function call directly in the 'IF' condition .

Tags: php, conditional-statements, php-5.3

Using PHP5.3, I can use a function directly in a condition,like this  :

```
if(my_function($var) == 'hello') {...}
```

But sometimes, even if I know what the function would return, I have a PHP bug and I have to do like this :

```
$result = another_function($var);
if($result == 'world') {...}
```

If both functions would return a string, why can I use the first and not the second ? I want to understand what the `if` condition can accept. Are all PHP natives functions are ok ? does the `if` condition doesn't want a method MyObject->my_function($var) ?

Comment: can we see the functions ? what error do you get ?

Comment: is this the error you are seeing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context

Comment: Like WayneC shows me, it's not about the condition but a limitation of empty(). Because It's always used in conditions I though others functions can have the same problem, thanks for that.