# Why is if(empty(strlen(trim($_POST['name'])))) invalid?

Tags: php

I have a if statement check to see if a string is empty

```
if(empty(strlen(trim($_POST['name'])))){
    $error_empty = true;
}
```

gives me this error:

> **Fatal error:** Can't use function return value in write context in **C:\xampp\htdocs\requestaccess\index.php** on line 51

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: What's the point of empty for a count? Your problem is here

Comment: @Fabio I want to trim a string of whitespace, then find if the string length is equal to zero. If it is, then `$error_empty` is set to true.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context

Comment: If `trim` writes its argument, you are in trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`empty` is not a function -- it's a "language construct" that prior to PHP 5.5 can only be used to evaluate variables, not the results of arbitrary expressions.

If you wanted to use `empty` in exactly this manner (*which is meaningless*) you would have to store the result in an intermediate variable:

```
$var = strlen(trim($_POST['name']));
if(empty($var)) ...
```

But you don't need to do anything like this: `strlen` will always return an integer, so `empty` will effectively be reduced to checking for zero. You don't need `empty` for that; zero converts to boolean `false` automatically, so a saner option is

```
if(!strlen(trim($_POST['name']))) ...
```

or the equivalent

```
if(trim($_POST['name']) === '') ...
```