# Can't use method return value in write context in

Tags: php

If i try do something like this:

```
  $title = $this->fullSearchForm->get('title')->getValue();
            if(!empty($title)) {
                echo "ok";
            }
```

evrything is ok.

But i below case

```
 if(!empty($this->fullSearchForm->get('title')->getValue())) {
        echo "OK";
    }
```

I get error

```
Can't use method return value in write context in
```

My php is from debian stable Whezzy PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (cli) (built: Feb 17 2014 09:18:47) 
Thanks for answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context

Comment: below PHP 5.5 its not allowed !! U need to check empty() as in ur first case. Empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error

Answer (score 2):

In your context, you should be using:

```
if( $this->fullSearchForm->get('title')->getValue()) {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Because `empty` checks if a variable is set and not falsy, but a function's return value is always "set" so basically it's just a check for falsiness.

`empty` operates on variables, NOT functions.