# Add div around validation_errors

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Hi i want to edit my validation_errors function that it will always have a div around it.
Im using bootstrap and there is a nice way to show errors with  Dismissable alerts [Look here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-dismissable)

I have found the function validation_errors() in system/helpers/form_helper.php which looks like:

```
if ( ! function_exists('validation_errors'))
{
    function validation_errors($prefix = '', $suffix = '')
    {
        if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
        {
            return '';
        }  
        return $OBJ->error_string($prefix, $suffix);
    }
}
```

How can i edit it that it returns :

```
     <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        errors here
     </div>
```

I know i shouldn't do it in a helper class because its bad when i update my codeigniter version, but i really do not know how it can be done in a diffrent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
if ( ! function_exists('validation_errors'))
{
    function validation_errors($prefix = '', $suffix = '')
    {
        if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
        {
            return '';
        }  
        return '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">'.$OBJ->error_string($prefix, $suffix).'</div>'
    }
}
```

or

```
<?php 
if(!empty(validation_errors())) {
   echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">'.validation_errors().'</div>';
}
?>
```

or if you really need to modify the helper

```
if ( ! function_exists('validation_errors'))
    {
        function validation_errors($prefix = '', $suffix = '')
        {
            if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
            {
                return '';
            }

            if($OBJ->error_string($prefix, $suffix) != '') {
              return '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">'.$OBJ->error_string($prefix, $suffix).'</div>';
            }
            else {
              return '';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes but it show the div, even when there are 0 errors.

Comment: Thats what i want to avoid, i dont want to type the error div in every view. i would need to change every view if i changed something in the alert div. if i can do it by default i wont need to change every view.

Comment: that gives me an error:  Can't use method return value in write context in line 604 , line 604 is if(!empty($OBJ->error_string($prefix, $suffix))) {  thanks for the help so far ;) @AbstractChaos

Comment: Works if i change it to if($OBJ->error_string($prefix, $suffix) != '') {        if you edit it in ur answer i will accept ;)

Comment: @SvenB hadnt spotted that, its due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context/4328049#4328049