# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, php-5.3

Error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/u566013465/public_html/2/inc/functions.php on line 2361
>   line 2361:

```
if( empty( shell_exec("which $command") ) ) {
    return false;
}

if( $config['debug'] ) {
    $start = microtime(true);
}
```

I have `PHP 5.3`

Comment: @Rizier123 If you use `return` out side of function, it will exit from current file!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use method return value in write context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

Comment: Very nice statement of the error message you are receiving. Thanks very much for the info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function can be used only for variables and if you pass anything else, it will throw a parse error:

```
$var  = shell_exec("which $command") ;
 if( empty( $var ) ) {
    return false;
}

if( $config['debug'] ) {
    $start = microtime(true);
}
```