# Why does empty() not accept function return value when it accepts getter output?

Tags: php

I'm having a class that implements the [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface. I noticed that I can use [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function on the offset values with no errors:

```
$class = new MyArrayClass();
if(!empty($class["offset"])) 
   ...
else
   die("Empty!!!");
```

However calling even the `offsetGet` interface method will not work:

```
if(!empty($class->offsetGet("offset")))
```

It throws standard error:

> **Can't use function return value in write context.**

My question is: Why does [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) work on [getters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and [virtual array offsets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetget.php)? As far as I know, they are actually function return values, not variables...

This question is rather educational then practical. I'm just curious. Please try to explain as much as possible.

Comment: Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context/4328049#4328049

Comment: Note that this will work fine if you use PHP 5.5+ (with a caveat on the `E_NOTICE`): http://3v4l.org/bG17l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) in php version less than 5.5 accepts only variables.

from changelog:

> 5.5.0     empty() now supports expressions, rather than only variables.