# How do I host Codeigniter in Server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting, codeigniter-3

I am a new of web developer. I try to host Codeigniter. Before I host, I edit the code in the config.php and my database:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mbl.myburgerlab.com.kh/';
```

But, I cannot and the error is:

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

Who can help me, please?

Comment: did you place the codeigniter installation on your server in the correct directory?

Comment: I use filezilla to upload my codeigniter folder

Comment: @user307709 Did you correctly point the domain to right folder?

Comment: This is my first time hosting

Comment: http://mbl.myburgerlab.com.kh/

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Where your folder is located? Is it directly in public_html folder or in subfolder within public_html?

Comment: You should point your domain to mbl folder then it will work..

Comment: I point already but still can not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94777/discussion-between-basheer-kharoti-and-user307709).

Comment: @user307709 Inner pages are still not working and getting can not use method return vlaue in write context error try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context/4328049#4328049

Comment: Thank bro now it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; # keep empty
```

In `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "";
```

> As well as check your **Spellings and Beware about case-sensitive**

Comment: What if base_url has been using through out the project?

Comment: CI auto detect `base_url()`. So no harm at all

Comment: 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: check your spellings. Thats the problem. Cz **Host is CaseSensitive**

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['mbl-admin'] = 'mbl-admin/mbl_login/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: An Error Was Encountered

Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.

Comment: check your route file its not uploaded or its empty

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['mbl-admin'] = 'mbl-admin/mbl_login/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: this is my first time hosting

Comment: make sure all the files are uploaded. show image of your controller folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94778/discussion-between-user307709-and-abdulla).

Comment: Very thz q brother it very work for me . thz u are kind bro :D