# Prestashop module weird issue

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am developing a custom module in prestashop. In that I have taken value inside a function like this

```
$fname = !empty(Tools::getValue('fname')) ? Tools::getValue('fname') : '';
```

but its showing error like this

`Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context`

So can someone tell me why the error is here? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use method return value in write context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

Comment: NewUser please mark and up-vote the answer, if it solves your problem, thanks. it will help others

Comment: @A-2-A thanks for the answer but that did not worked. This worked for me `Tools::getValue('fname') ? Tools::getValue('fname') : ' ';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. It should be like this

`Tools::getValue('fname') ? Tools::getValue('fname') : ' ';`

Comment: I don't know but I tried that and it worked. You can check that

Comment: Its unbelievable that my code didn't work. Since not helpful  deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I just will explain it here for someone from google results.

1. `empty(someFunction())` creates error, because

> Note:
>   Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

2. In Prestashop method `Tools::getValue()` have possibility to use default value,

   public static function getValue($key, $default_value = false)
       {

so you can use `Tools::getValue('fname', '');` and returned value will contain or value of 'fname' or empty string, in this case.