# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/gdcrpgin/public_html/manage_mypage.php on line 79

Tags: php, html, mysql, function

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/gdcrpgin/public_html/manage_mypage.php on line 79

The complete web project was working fine until it was on my local windows machine since i uploaded this to online linux server (Hostgator) one of my page started showing this error I don't have any idea what this error mean i tried troubleshooting it at my level but nothing was achieved.

Line 79 is

```
<input type="text" name="home" class="form-control" maxlength="60" value = "<?php if(!empty(getuserfield($conn,"home"))) echo getuserfield($conn,"home") ?>"  required>
```

Function getuserfield() return nothing more than "Fake" string.
I commented out its actual work to see it helps or not but no luck.

```
function getuserfield($conn,$field)
{
    /*
    $table = $_SESSION['type'];
    $key = $_SESSION['key'];
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];  
    $query = "select $field from $table where $key = '$user'";  
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));    
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)){
    if(!empty($fetch[0]))
        return $fetch[0];
    else
        return null;
    }*/
    return "Fake";
}
```

Comment: Is this the only place where you are getting an/this error?

Comment: yeah this is the only page where i am getting this error but if i comment out the line 79 then it gives same error on line 85 

<input type="text" name="home_link" class="form-control"  value = "<?php if(!empty(getuserfield($conn,"home_link"))) echo getuserfield($conn,"home_link") ?>" required>

but not in the first textbox that have no empty check 

<input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "username" value = "<?php echo getuserfield($conn,"username");?>" disabled>

Answer (score 1):

One google query about your problem got me the the solution to your problem (probably). If this is indeed the answer, you're probably guilty of not doing any research before coming here, shame.

You can find the solution here: [Can't use method return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

You're probably running an old version of php. This seems VERY likely since your application used to work, and now it doesn't on a "new" environment. The function `empty()` (so it's not about your `getuserfield()`) can only accept expressions since PHP 5.5.

So to fix your problem, install a newer version of PHP.

Comment: I don't think hostgator will allow me to intall a new version of PHP on their server and i really dont want to downgrade my site and change almost 3 KLOC I have used this techniques so many times in the web project
I did search about the error but didn't find any clue about incompatibility

Comment: If  you follow the link I've provided you'll see that you're doing the same the poster of the other question has asked. What version of PHP are they running? If you find that they're running an old version you should ask yourself why on earth you're hosting your application there. If you NEED to run it there and they don't want to install a new version, then you're forced to downgrade, but then again, if these were your constraints you obviously shouldn't have developed your application on a newer version.

Comment: HostGator allows you to update the version: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/what-version-of-php-are-you-using

Comment: Thanks dude for the information they are running PHP 5 actually this is my first web project that is so big for me previously I coded some small application using php 5.5 and had no problem hosting them on hostgator. Ur information saved my day.Now I will not have to go  backward and code again with php 5.0 standards.

Answer (score 1):

`empty` is used to test whether **a variable** doesn't exist or is *falsey*. You're using it on the return value of a *function*. Those are incompatible uses. Get rid of `empty`, you don't need it here. `if (getuserfield(..))` does exactly the same thing for a function.

It happens to work on another server because since PHP 5.5, `empty` also accepts expressions of any sort. One of your servers has PHP 5.5, the other something older. Though `empty` is still used superfluously here.

You should always be aware of the PHP version you're using to develop, where you're going to deploy to, and that both should be identical or at least the same major release version.

Comment: Your first paragraph is sense less but others two totally makes a great sense which i totally agree with.

You can see i called the function in the value property of a text box and it is returning value form db what if there is nothing in db for that specific field it will fill the textbox value property with php error in html formate.

Comment: "Senseless"?! Wow, uhm, thanks a bunch. You may want to read this: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)