# Compile Error Can't use method return value in write context in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, hmvc

i got this model which inserts data on the database but the problem is, other fields are not required so i did this,

```
public function insert(){


    if($this->input->post('MNAME') = NULL){
        $mname = "n/a";
    }else{
        $mname = $this->input->post('MNAME');
    }

    if($this->input->post('EXTENSION') = NULL){
        $ext = "n/a";
    }else{
        $ext = $this->input->post('EXTENSION');
    }

    if($this->input->post('EMAIL') = NULL){
        $email = "n/a";
    }else{
        $email = $this->input->post('EMAIL');
    }

    if($this->input->post('CELLNO') = NULL){
        $cell = "n/a";
    }else{
        $cell = $this->input->post('CELLNO');
    }

    if($this->input->post('AGENCY_NO') = NULL){
        $agency = "n/a";
    }else{
        $agency = $this->input->post('AGENCY_NO');
    }

    $input = array(
        'ID_NUM'        => $this->uri->segment(3),
        'FNAME'         => $this->input->post('FNAME'       ),
        'SURNAME'       => $this->input->post('SURNAME'     ),
        'DO_BIRTH'      => $this->input->post('DO_BIRTH'    ),
        'POBIRTH'       => $this->input->post('POBIRTH'     ),
        'SEX'           => $this->input->post('SEX'         ),
        'CIVILSTAT'     => $this->input->post('CIVILSTAT'   ),
        'ID_NAT'        => $this->input->post('ID_NAT'      ),
        'HEIGHT'        => $this->input->post('HEIGHT'      ),
        'WEIGHT'        => $this->input->post('WEIGHT'      ),
        'BLOOD_TYPE'    => $this->input->post('BLOOD_TYPE'  ),
        'RES_ADD'       => $this->input->post('RES_ADD'     ),
        'RES_ZIP'       => $this->input->post('RES_ZIP'     ),
        'PERM_ADD'      => $this->input->post('PERM_ADD'    ),
        'PERM_ZIP'      => $this->input->post('PERM_ZIP'    ),
        'MNAME'         => $mname,
        'EXTENSION'     => $ext,
        'EMAIL'         => $email,
        'CELLNO'        => $cell,       
        'AGENCY_NO'     => $agency,
        'DATE_CREATED'  => date("Y-m-d")
        );

    $insert = $this->db->insert($this->table,$input);

    return $insert;
}
```

but the problem is that i get this error `Can't use method return value in write context` says that its on line  108. which, the line 108 is the first if of my model. what is my error? and is there any codes which will be shorter?

Comment: All your if conditions are invalid, you are trying to assign NULL values to method calls.

Comment: Your statements, you need two `==`'s to check a match

Comment: check it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4328049/6079755 this is the correct way you need implemente it.

Answer (score 0):

> You're only stating 1 `=` in your **IF** statements, for future note: It should be 2 `=`'s in a match.

I restructured this for you so your code is more readable and short.

```
// Checking if they're null and appending n/a if they're
$example = array('MNAME','EXTENSION','EMAIL', 'CELLNO', 'AGENCY_NO');
$new = array();
foreach ($example as $_ex)
{
    $check = $this->input->post($_ex);
    if ($check == null)? array_push($new, 'n/a') : array_push($new, $check);
}
```

Then replace with this (keeping in mind index's start at **0** in an array):

```
// Inside your DB insert query
'MNAME'         => $new[0],
'EXTENSION'     => $new[1],
'EMAIL'         => $new[2],
'CELLNO'        => $new[3],       
'AGENCY_NO'     => $new[4],
```

I hope this helped.