# PHP Error - 'Can't use function return value in write context'

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I just got this error on a page that is meant to show some product categories:

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/name/public_html/wp-content/themes/name/taxonomy-prodcat.php on line 37

On line 37 is this code:

```
<?php if(!empty(get_field('product_size', get_the_ID()))): ?>
                                            <p class="producttext"><span class="boldproduct">Size -</span> <?php echo get_field('product_size', get_the_ID()); ?></p>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
```

PHP Version 5.6.30
MySQL Version   5.6.35

I really cant find the problem. Any help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context

Comment: just echo this code get_field('product_size', get_the_ID()), What is the output

Comment: @cornelb my phpversion is above 5.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use method return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

Answer (score 0):

You must write:

$v = get_field(...);
if(!empty($v))...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$values = get_field( 'product_size' , get_the_ID());
if ( $values ) { ?>
    <p class="producttext"><span class="boldproduct">Size -</span> <?php echo get_field('product_size', get_the_ID()); ?></p>
<?php
} ?>
```

Comment: the logic is the same