# Ternary Function - Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a ternary function just to check if a value is empty or not.But its returning a fatal error

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /home/sommelie/food.toogoodtogo.hu/wp-content/themes/...../woocommerce/config.woocommerce.php
>   on line 551

```
 $shipping = !empty(get_post_meta( $restaurant_id, 'delivery_charge', true )) ? get_post_meta( $restaurant_id, 'delivery_charge', true ) : '0.00';
```

What could be a possible error?is there any error, i don't think so because it works on my server but not this current one.

I am not understanding why it's happening.This is a part of a wordpress theme.

Comment: What is the PHP version on the server where it doesn't work?

Comment: "But its returning a fatal error" which issssssssss? It would help us determine the problem if you actually let us know what the error is.

Comment: This code snippet is incomplete.  I tried it and had the error, `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_post_meta()`.  Please post a complete code sample and the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use method return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

Comment: @JBH It would be incredibly hard to provide that information more than likely as it would require database structures and probably multiple functions.

Comment: you can't call `empty` on a function call before php 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble when trying to use `empty` with a function call

```
empty(someFunction());
```

You should declare a variable to store the post medatata. Or your code will call 2 times the `get_post_meta()` if the first call return something. It isn't needed :)

```
 $postMetadata = get_post_meta( $restaurant_id, 'delivery_charge', true );
 $shipping = !empty($postMetadata) ? $postMetadata : '0.00';
```