# Unset some data from create_order( $data ) inside WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Im trying to clean up some default database entries that WooCommerce adds to the postmeta table. The two primary entries that I do not need are `_customers_ip_address` & `_customer_user_agent`.

I found `_customers_ip_address` in `create_order()` function in file `class-wc-checkout.php`

`do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data );` seems to be what is setting the data. Although I also found it was being set in `wc-core-functions.php` @ `function wc_create_order()`

Im not 100% sure how to edit this. Im thinking a simple `do_filter`, but `unset` seems to not work inside the `do_filter`, but obviously I am doing it all wrong. Im not that familiar with `do_filter` but seems like something simple like the code below.

```
function cleanup_woocommerce_checkout_create_order($order, $data) {
    unset($order->set_customer_ip_address());
    return $order;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'cleanup_woocommerce_checkout_create_order');
```

The code above gives a WordPress Error of :

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use method return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

Comment: Not a duplication, this is WooCommerce/WordPress specific. Im not asking about the error message, I just put in there to let anyone know the sample code I wrote doesn't work with do_filter as a WordPress function.

Answer (score 1):

First `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` is an action hook (but not a filter hook). Also you can not unset any method applied to an object as you are doing.

What you can do is to try setting an empty value, like:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'cleanup_specific_order_metadata', 10, 2 );
function cleanup_specific_order_metadata( $order, $data ) {
    $order->set_customer_ip_address('');
    $order->set_customer_user_agent('');
}
```

It should work.

**If it doesn't work**, you can try to use `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` action hook to remove this meta data afterwards once order data has been saved to database, this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'cleanup_specific_order_metadata', 10, 2 );
function cleanup_specific_order_metadata( $order_id, $data ) {
    delete_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_ip_address' );
    delete_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user_agent' );
}
```

This last one should work anyways.

Comment: The top add_action, didn't work. Your second method is a creative work around, and might be my last ditch effort if I can't find an official way to unset it from create order. As mentioned in a previous comment I actually found another place it's being set in wc_core_functions.php in function wc_create_order( ) which I will updated the original post to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in this article, https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#397

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data );
```

so you should use add_action function

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'cleanup_woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 10, 2 );

function cleanup_woocommerce_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    $order->set_customer_ip_address(0);
}
```

Or updating the post meta

```
update_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_ip_address', 0);
```

or

```
delete_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_ip_address');
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I tried you idea but it's still populating the _customer_ip_address in the database upon checkout. I'll look over the apidocs link and see if maybe I can come up with something there. I also found it is getting set in wc_core_functions.php in function wc_create_order( ) so this one could be overwriting this add_action.

Comment: Have you tried updating the post meta after order is created? I have updated the answer

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec beat you to this one :) Both of you are thinking outside the box, which is awesome! And a very good approach that I might have to use if I don't find a way to unset on order creation.

Comment: haha yeah.. I had a look into the woocommerce class and set_customer_ip_address (0) should work but dunno! Updating the post meta is not something wrong. It's a wordpress funcion, you could use that!

Comment: Yes deleting after the fact is an option. It's an extra database query so would be nice to just unset it on the original database insert to save a little server processing. But so small I might have to end up using that approach. Thanks for your feedback.