# How to fix: "can't return value"

Tags: php, codeigniter

### Can't use method return value in CODEIGNITER FIX ERROR

```
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();

    $group_data = array();
 if(empty($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))){
        $session_data = array('logged_in' => FALSE);
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
    }
    else {
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->load->model('model_groups');
        $group_data = $this->model_groups->getUserGroupByUserId($user_id);

        $this->data['user_permission'] = unserialize($group_data['permission']);
        $this->permission = unserialize($group_data['permission']);
    }
}
```

1. Installation error
2. CODEIGNITER MVC
3. How to fix it

Comment: class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller 
{
 var $permission = array();

Comment: create class after this error in   this  lineif(empty($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))){

Comment: error is Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context - please _research_ the error messages you get, if you can’t manage to understand them on your own.

Comment: Try replacing you `if` statement with `if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!==NULL)`.

Comment: Formatting improved, but the question could use some more elaboration